# monitor changes in a folder windows 7

Tags: compare

Ultimately, I want a way (a free way) to monitor changes in a folder and then output those changes to text file. Now this would need to be done programmatically as im using autohotkey to start the process and id like it if it was unseen by the user. I've tried copying the contents of the folder to text file before the change then after the change then using findstr to compare the two and only output the difference to text file. But, findstr outputs false positives. It would output file names as differences even though I can visually confirm they are the same in both files. I need something similar to findstr.

I need something to work like this:

file1.txt

```
file1.mp3
file2.mp3
file3.mp3
```

file2.txt

```
file1.mp3
file2.mp3
file3.mp3
file4.mp3
```

diff.txt

```
file4.mp3
```

Findstr works exactly how I need it to work except for the errors.

```
findstr /lv /g:file1.txt file2.txt>diff.txt
```

The error I speak of is with the case sensitivity on, I get 2 files in diff.txt that I know are the same in file1.txt and file2.txt. With case sensitivity off, I get like 30 0r 40 files that are the same in both.
Autohotkey has a very round-about way to accomplish this but I would much prefer a simpler way. Either batch, vbs, or anything else that will run natively on windows 7 or a standalone exe. Something relatively simple and free.

What I am trying to achieve is whatever file is added to the folder, a text file is then created, with the same file name minus the extension, and added to dropbox then IFTTT detects the file and notifies me via sms that 'filename' has finished downloading.

I finished and perfected the method of texting the download link to my pc (via a combination of AHK, batch and IFTTT) which automatically downloads the file. Now I just want a way to be notified its done.